# java.lang.IllegalStateException thrown when trying to send sms in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to send an sms to a fixed number (practically between two virtual devices) when i click a button, but when i press it this exception is thrown.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.expert.myapplication, PID: 4454
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
               Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10079 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
                  at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendTextForSubscriber(ISms.java:789)
                  at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal(SmsManager.java:329)
                  at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:312)
                  at com.example.expert.myapplication.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:103)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

here is some simple code i found that should work for two phones that run in vms but here it doesn't for no apparent reason

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

 private Button button3;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.SEND);
    }

 public void onClick(View view) {
        String number = "6942649512";
        String message= "Help";

        //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        // PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,0);

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(number, null,message,null,null);


        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

    }
}
```

Also i have added the sms permission in the manifest.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10079 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
```

Which means that you don't have permission to send sms. So please try to add SMS permission into Android Manifest and if you use API 23 >= ,you need to request for user permission.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},1);
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Please take a look more about [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: Thank you i needed to add the request for the permission inside my  button.